# Why does my html page fail to render the same after making it standalone?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I have a web page (Web API/ASP.NET) that looks pretty much as I want it to:

[image]

This is the code that produces it:

```
@model WebAppRptScheduler.Models.HomeModel
@using System.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PRO*ACT eServices Reporting";

    DataTable dtUnits = Model.Units;
    var units = from x in dtUnits.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                    unit = x.Field<string>("unit")
                };

    DataTable dtReports = Model.Reports;
    var reports = from x in dtReports.AsEnumerable()
                  select new
                  {
                      report = x.Field<string>("ReportName").ToUpper()
                  };

    List<String> daysOfMonth = Model.DaysOfMonth;
    List<String> ordinalWeeksOfMonth = Model.OrdinalWeek;
    List<String> daysOfWeek = Model.DaysOfWeek;
    List<String> patternFrequency = Model.PatternFrequency;

    int maxMonthsBackBegin = Model.maxMonthsBackForReportBegin;
    int maxMonthsBackEndNormal = Model.maxMonthsBackForReportEndNormal;
    int maxMonthsBackEndFillRate = Model.maxMonthsBackForReportEndFillRate;
    int maxDaysBackForDeliveryPerformance = Model.maxDaysBackForDeliveryPerformanceReport;
}

@* row 1: "Report Scheduler" *@
<div class="jumbotronjr">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://www.proactusa.com/wp-content/themes/proact/images/pa_logo_notag.png" alt="PRO*ACT usa logo">
        @*<img src="~/Content/Images/proactLogoWithVerbiage.png" alt="PRO*ACT usa puny logo">*@
        @*<img src="~/Content/Images/proactLogoWithVerbiage.png" height="160" width="200" alt="PRO*ACT usa puny logo">*@
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <label class="titletext">eServices Reporting</label>
    </div>
</div>

@* row 2: HR *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>

@* row 3: "Select Distributors, -Categories, -Report Date Range" *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Select Distributors</label>
        <div>
            <select class="dropdown bottommarginbreathingroom" id="unitsselect" name="unitsselect">
                <option disabled selected value="-1">Please choose a Distributor</option>
                <option>All Distributors</option>
                <option>FSA Loveland</option>
                <option>Hearn Kirkwood</option>
                <option>Paragon</option>
                <option>Piazza</option>
                <option>ProduceOne Cleveland</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Select Categories</label>
        <div>
            <select class="dropdown bottommarginbreathingroom" id="categoriesselect" name="categoriesselect">
                <option disabled selected value="-1">Please choose Categories</option>
                <option>All Categories</option>
                <option>Fruits</option>
                <option>Vegetables</option>
                <option>Herbs</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Report Date Range</label>
        <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom1" name="daterangefrom1">
            </input>
            <label> to </label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto1" name="daterangeto1">
            </input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@* row 4: "Select Classes, Comparative Date Range" *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Select Classes</label>
        <div>
            <select class="dropdown bottommarginbreathingroom" id="customersselect" name="customersselect">
                <option disabled selected value="-1">Please choose Classes</option>
                <option>All Classes</option>
                <option>Apples</option>
                <option>Asparagus</option>
                <option>Avocados</option>
                <option>Bananas</option>
                <option>Beans</option>
                <option>Berries</option>
                <option>Broccoli</option>
                <option>Cabbage</option>
                <option>Carrots</option>
                <option>Celery</option>
                <option>Cilantro</option>
                <option>Cucumbers</option>
                <option>Garlic</option>
                <option>Grapes</option>
                <option>Lettuce</option>
                <option>Peppers</option>
                <option>Potatoes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Comparative Date Range</label>
        <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom2" name="daterangefrom2">
            </input>
            <label> to </label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto2" name="daterangeto2">
            </input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@* row 5: "Select Items, Summary and Detail checkboxes, Submit button"  *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Select Items</label>
        <div>
            <select class="dropdown bottommarginbreathingroom" id="itemssselect" name="itemssselect">
                <option disabled selected value="-1">Please choose Items</option>
                <option>All Items</option>
                <option>APPLES, FUJI 12/3#</option>
                <option>APPLES, GRANNY SMITH 20 CT</option>
                <option>ASPARAGUS, LARGE 11/1#</option>
                <option>AVOCADOS, HASS 48 #1</option>
                <option>BANANAS, 10#</option>
                <option>BEANS, GREEN TRIM 2/5# (BAGS)</option>
                <option>BERRIES, BLACK 1/6 OZ</option>
                <option>BERRIES, BLUE 1/6 OZ</option>
                <option>BERRIES, RASPBERRY 3/6 OZ</option>
                <option>BERRIES, STRAWBERRY 1# CLAM</option>
                <option>BROCCOLI, 14 CT</option>
                <option>BRUSSEL SPROUTS, 25#</option>
                <option>CABBAGE, GREEN 5#</option>
                <option>CABBAGE, RED 5#</option>
                <option>CELERY, 24 CT</option>
                <option>CILANTRO, ICELESS 1/6 CT</option>
                <option>CUCUMBERS, SELECT 5#</option>
                <option>GARLIC, PEELED 1/5# BAG</option>
                <option>GRAPES, RED SEEDLESS 5#</option>
                <option>HERBS, ARUGULA 1#</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <br/>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="summary" value="summary"> Summary
        <input type="checkbox" name="detail" value="detail"> Detail
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary green marginaboveandbelow" style="padding: 6px 50px 6px 50px; margin-left: -24px;" id="btnGetData" name="btnGetData">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</div>

@* row 6: HR *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>

@* row 7: Copy, Excel, CSV, and PDF buttons; Search label and input text  *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Copy</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Excel</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">CSV</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">PDF</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 ">
        <label style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 2px">Search:</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" style="margin-left: -1cm; margin-right: 2cm;" name="searchinput">
    </div>
</div>

@* row 8: HR *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>

@* row 9: HTML Table with fake summary data *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Distributor</th>
                <th>Packages</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Percentage of Total</th>
            <tr>
                <td>FSA Loveland</td>
                <td>1.0</td>
                <td>30.74</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hearn Kirkwood</td>
                <td>10.0</td>
                <td>309.49</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paragon</td>
                <td>100.0</td>
                <td>3000.27</td>
                <td>19</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Piazza</td>
                <td>1000.0</td>
                <td>30012.62</td>
                <td>28</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ProduceOne Cleveland</td>
                <td>10000.0</td>
                <td>309871.18</td>
                <td>42</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to send it as a file (bla.html), so I created the following, which uses Bootstrap via CDN, and adds the custom CSS classes in the style section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>eServices Reporting - Summary Data</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- Inline CSS (don't tell the CSS-Whisperers I did this!) -->
<style>
.jumbotronjr {
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 2.1428571435;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
.titletext {
    font-size: 2.8em;
    color: darkgreen;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
    margin-left: -32px;
}
.addltopmargin {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.sectiontext {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
}
.bottommarginbreathingroom {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.marginaboveandbelow {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.btn.green{
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color: white;
}
.squishedbutton {
  margin-left: 0cm;
  margin-right: -0.1cm;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="jumbotronjr">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://www.proactusa.com/wp-content/themes/proact/images/pa_logo_notag.png" alt="PRO*ACT usa logo">
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <label class="titletext">eServices Reporting</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Select Distributors</label>
        <div>
            <select class="dropdown bottommarginbreathingroom" id="unitsselect" name="unitsselect">
                <option disabled selected value="-1">Please choose a Distributor</option>
                <option>All Distributors</option>
                <option>FSA Loveland</option>
                <option>Hearn Kirkwood</option>
                <option>Paragon</option>
                <option>Piazza</option>
                <option>ProduceOne Cleveland</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Select Categories</label>
        <div>
            <select class="dropdown bottommarginbreathingroom" id="categoriesselect" name="categoriesselect">
                <option disabled selected value="-1">Please choose Categories</option>
                <option>All Categories</option>
                <option>Fruits</option>
                <option>Vegetables</option>
                <option>Herbs</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Report Date Range</label>
        <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom1" name="daterangefrom1">
            </input>
            <label> to </label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto1" name="daterangeto1">
            </input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Select Classes</label>
        <div>
            <select class="dropdown bottommarginbreathingroom" id="customersselect" name="customersselect">
                <option disabled selected value="-1">Please choose Classes</option>
                <option>All Classes</option>
                <option>Apples</option>
                <option>Asparagus</option>
                <option>Avocados</option>
                <option>Bananas</option>
                <option>Beans</option>
                <option>Berries</option>
                <option>Broccoli</option>
                <option>Cabbage</option>
                <option>Carrots</option>
                <option>Celery</option>
                <option>Cilantro</option>
                <option>Cucumbers</option>
                <option>Garlic</option>
                <option>Grapes</option>
                <option>Lettuce</option>
                <option>Peppers</option>
                <option>Potatoes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Comparative Date Range</label>
        <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom2" name="daterangefrom2">
            </input>
            <label> to </label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto2" name="daterangeto2">
            </input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 addltopmargin">
        <label class="sectiontext">Select Items</label>
        <div>
            <select class="dropdown bottommarginbreathingroom" id="itemssselect" name="itemssselect">
                <option disabled selected value="-1">Please choose Items</option>
                <option>All Items</option>
                <option>APPLES, FUJI 12/3#</option>
                <option>APPLES, GRANNY SMITH 20 CT</option>
                <option>ASPARAGUS, LARGE 11/1#</option>
                <option>AVOCADOS, HASS 48 #1</option>
                <option>BANANAS, 10#</option>
                <option>BEANS, GREEN TRIM 2/5# (BAGS)</option>
                <option>BERRIES, BLACK 1/6 OZ</option>
                <option>BERRIES, BLUE 1/6 OZ</option>
                <option>BERRIES, RASPBERRY 3/6 OZ</option>
                <option>BERRIES, STRAWBERRY 1# CLAM</option>
                <option>BROCCOLI, 14 CT</option>
                <option>BRUSSEL SPROUTS, 25#</option>
                <option>CABBAGE, GREEN 5#</option>
                <option>CABBAGE, RED 5#</option>
                <option>CELERY, 24 CT</option>
                <option>CILANTRO, ICELESS 1/6 CT</option>
                <option>CUCUMBERS, SELECT 5#</option>
                <option>GARLIC, PEELED 1/5# BAG</option>
                <option>GRAPES, RED SEEDLESS 5#</option>
                <option>HERBS, ARUGULA 1#</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <br/>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="summary" value="summary"> Summary
        <input type="checkbox" name="detail" value="detail"> Detail
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary green marginaboveandbelow" style="padding: 6px 50px 6px 50px; margin-left: -24px;" id="btnGetData" name="btnGetData">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Copy</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Excel</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">CSV</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">PDF</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 2px">Search:</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" style="margin-left: -1cm; margin-right: 2cm;" name="searchinput">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Distributor</th>
                <th>Packages</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Percentage of Total</th>
            <tr>
                <td>FSA Loveland</td>
                <td>1.0</td>
                <td>30.74</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hearn Kirkwood</td>
                <td>10.0</td>
                <td>309.49</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paragon</td>
                <td>100.0</td>
                <td>3000.27</td>
                <td>19</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Piazza</td>
                <td>1000.0</td>
                <td>30012.62</td>
                <td>28</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ProduceOne Cleveland</td>
                <td>10000.0</td>
                <td>309871.18</td>
                <td>42</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

...but quite a bit is lost in the translation. It looks like this:

[image]

So as you can see, my border has disappeared, the HRs are fainter than a narcoleptic on a lazy boy, and the html table is a complete mess.

But why, and how can I fix it? Why does my standalone html page fail to render non-uglily, even though I'm referencing the Bootstrap classes which the page uses?

### UPDATE

Thanks to stackingjasoncooper's comment, I got the table looking better by adding this CSS:

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Adding these helped, too:

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    color: navy;
    background: #333;
}
.body-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
   padding-left: 1px;
   padding-right: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

### UPDATE 3

Okay, this is the final thing I needed to add: _Layout.cshtml contains this in the head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

...and this in the body:

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

...so I added the first to the head (don't know if it's necessary, but it doesn't hurt anything), and the div as the first one inside the body section, and it looks exactly the same now.

Comment: You're still missing some CSS. For example, Bootstrap won't set alternating table row colors without calling a class, which you're not doing. The alternating row colors are not in your styles in your <head> either. Check your .NET app's head component or view source in your browser of that .NET page and look for additional stylesheets.

Comment: Make this into an answer, and I'll accept it (see my updates, especially the last one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your standalone page doesn't match your .NET page**
You're still missing some CSS. For example, Bootstrap won't set alternating table row colors without calling a class, which you're not doing. The alternating row colors are not in your styles in your `<head>` either. Check your .NET app's head component or view source in your browser of that .NET page and look for additional stylesheets.

Regarding your updates:

**Viewport tag**
The [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) helps scale your website for different screen sizes, like tablets and phones. With the very standard version you have, you're basically saying scale the website to fit the screen.

**@RenderBody()**
I think this is a .NET control. I don't think it will have any effect on an HTML page, so I don't think you need it.

**Bootstrap is awesome**
You're using the [Bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/), which has a lot of the CSS styles you're writing already built in. For example, check out the [Bootstrap table styles](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables). They're already done and available; you just have to call the classes. Have fun with it!